# PostgreSQL Failing to Start Even after Reinstalling on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, postgresql

It's been some months since I've last used PostgreSQL on my Arch Linux desktop, and, apparently, after some updates, something must have broken. If I ask for the service's status, I get (`systemctl status postgresql`):

```
× postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2024-02-21 16:00:22 -03; 1h 28min ago
        CPU: 54ms

fev 21 16:00:22 phili systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL database server...
fev 21 16:00:22 phili postgres[11667]: An old version of the database format was found.
fev 21 16:00:22 phili postgres[11667]: See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PostgreSQL#>
fev 21 16:00:22 phili systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Control process exited, code=exited, >
fev 21 16:00:22 phili systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
fev 21 16:00:22 phili systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL database server.
```

I've already tried to reinstall in various ways. But mostly with something like this:

```bash
pacman -Rsn postgresql
rm -rf /var/lib/postgres
pacman -Syu postgresql
```

The version I'm installing is the latest one, 16, but I've already tried all this with 14 as well. And, yes, I have tried restarting my PC several times.

Comment: The error you posted says `An old version of the database format was found` and provides a link `See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PostgreSQL#`.  You should read that link to make sure you update your database to the correct version for your installed version of PostgreSQL.  Make sure you have a backup of your database first before trying to make changes.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. But in my case I quite frankly don't have any data I would like to keep. Instead, if I could just uninstall everything and start with a clean install, that would be great. Do you see anything I'm missing in terms of reinstalling things?

Comment: The only relevant section I could find in that page was [this one](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PostgreSQL#Failing_to_start_a_PostgreSQL_server_with_the_older_version_of_the_database_while_upgrading_to_the_newer_version_with_extensions), but it seems to be about confusing (it's not 100% about PostgreSQL?) and dangerous.

Comment: Psygo: everything's fine with your (re)installation! It's not clear why you think you need to reinstall anything? Your database server, as GracefulRestart points out, is complaining about the data. Reinstalling the database server won't fix that… so: remove your data, if you don't need it?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, thanks for confirming that what I did was ok. I think it's actually complaining about the database format and not the data itself? Anyways, how do I reset those then?

Comment: The section pertaining to your issue is [section 8 regarding the upgrade process](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PostgreSQL#Upgrading_PostgreSQL).  If you would like to keep your data, you would need to make sure the database data is upgraded to the proper version using `pg_upgrade`

Comment: @GracefulRestart, thank you for the specific link. I think I mostly followed steps 3, 5, and 6, and it was enough. If you create an answer based on that, I would accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initialize a PostgreSQL database, the database data is keyed to to that major version of PostgreSQL.

When you upgrade the major version of PostgreSQL, you need to make sure the database data is compatible with that new version.

Arch Linux provides a [wiki entry for exactly this scenario](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PostgreSQL#Upgrading_PostgreSQL), the steps are summarized as follows:

0. Make a backup of your database data
1. Try to retrieve the `initdb` arguments used to create the initial database
2. Stop the `postgresql.service`
3. Upgrade all the PostgreSQL packages
4. Delete any existing old data from previous database upgrades
5. Move your database data to a temporary location and make a new directory to store the upgraded database.
6. Initialize a new database with the same `initdb` arguments as the original database.
7. Upgrade your previous database with `pg_upgrade`
8. Start the `postgresql.service`

Sans any errors, your PostgreSQL database server should now be running with upgraded database.  You can now clean up any old data and temporary directories if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Following some of @GracefulRestart's comments, what works in the end for me was following *some* of the steps in the [8.1 `pg_upgrade`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PostgreSQL#Upgrading_PostgreSQL) section:

1. Installing `postgresql-old-upgrade`
2. Rename the old cluster directory, then create a new cluster and temporary working directory:

   ```bash
   mv /var/lib/postgres/data /var/lib/postgres/olddata
   mkdir /var/lib/postgres/data /var/lib/postgres/tmp
   chown postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgres/data /var/lib/postgres/tmp
   ```
3. Initialize the new cluster using the same initdb arguments as were used for the old cluster:

   ```bash
   [postgres]$ initdb -D /var/lib/postgres/data --locale=C.UTF-8 --encoding=UTF8 --data-checksums
   ```